# onblur event not working in ie; works fine with chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, onblur

i have a code in which am trying to trigger a function for onblur event. but onblur event does not get triggered in IE.
Works well with firefox and chrome... But not sure whats wrong in IE.

```
<p>
    <label for="email">Username or E-mail Id </label>
    <input type="text" id="input" maxlength="35" onblur="validate()">
<p>
```

I did a search and found few answers, but they don't work.

I've found the same issue with onchange event in dropdown menu as well
thanks in advance,
Samuel Mathews.

Comment: It would be very useful to see the code...

Comment: @Saran i've updated with the code. thanks!

Comment: @SamuelMathews, it works under IE for me (http://jsfiddle.net/Kc9gh/3/), blur event is fired as expected. Maybe issue is your validate() function?

Comment: yeah, check your console for logged errors. Set a break point in your validate method and step through the code in the F12 debugger. You can see what is happening in your method there.

Comment: please find the other code below... can you please help me... 

    function validate()  
    input="";email="";username="";pwd="";
    input=(document.getElementById("input").value).trim(); 
    pwd=(document.getElementById("pwd").value);
    {   var x=input;var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
      var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
      if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
      { username=input;   check_username.call(); }
       else
        {email=input;
        check_email.call(); }  }  }

Comment: hi everyone...
can you please help me resolve the issue... the onblur doesn't still work in IE alone... when i check i get an error msg - object doesn't support this method or property.. 
any idea please.. thanks in advance!

Comment: hi guys... thanks all for your support.. 
i replaced onblur event with focusout jquery.. tat worked across browsers.. thanks again!